# How can I align this system of equations?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, texshop, mactex

I am trying to solve this problem since two days and I wasn't able to find anything that could fix it.

I wan this two equations in the system to be both aligned to the left and well ordered, without all those blank spaces. I will post the code:

[image]

Is there a way to keep the curly bracket of the system and align those two to the left, deleting all those blank spaces that can be seen in the following photo?

[image]

By the way, I am using LaTeX.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please -- as usual here -- show us a complete short tex code in your question by copy and paste, because we can not copy and test an tex code given in an image ... Make the code compilable, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: With the `systeme` package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it as follows:

```
\[\left\{
  \begin{array}{l}
    2x-5y-z=3\\
    2x^2=y
  \end{array}
\right.\]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I really appreciated your help.

Answer (score 6):

With `cases`:

```
\[ \begin{cases} 2x-5y-z=2\\ 2x^2=y \end{cases} \]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was aware of this command, but I though it should have been used only when defining equation which depends on certain conditions, and not for systems of equations too. Anyways, thank you very much.